# How to get MAC Address without using IP Address in java socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

I am New in socket programming in Java.Can someone tell me , how to get MAC Address  without using IP Address in socket programming.

This is the code by which i can get MAC address in socket--

NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

```
    byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

    System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-              " : ""));      
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

but this is using IP Address ultimately.Is there any way to get the MAC Address without using IP Address?

Comment: Any PC's MAC ADDRESS by using socket

Comment: For what purpose? Are you aware that a MAC address isn't reliable as a unique system identifier?

Comment: actually i had a project on that which has remote desktop facility but ip independent.So, I thought if i get MAC address, then it could be possible

Comment: what is the code in socket programming in java to get MAC ADDRESS without using IP ADDRESS. Can you suggest?

Comment: @user1825660 You can't do anything useful with a MAC address in Java except print it.

Comment: In that case, If I want to do a remote desktop application without using IP address(it was the actual requirement) in java-socket, how can i do that?..please help

Answer (score 2):

> Any PC's MAC ADDRESS by using socket

In a nutshell, there is no reliable method for finding out the MAC address of a host outside your subnet.

If you are on the same subnet as the host in question, take a look at [ARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) and [RARP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Address_Resolution_Protocol).

Comment: Note, that ARP/RARP isn't a feature in IPv6 nets.

Answer (score 1):

MAC addresses are only used on local networks. It is the way a switch/router knows where a packet has to be sent. IP is used to transport packets from network to network.

All TCP/UDP packets include senders IP and MAC. This way the receiving device can include the MAC in the return package so the switch/router know where to deliver it. MAC addresses should be unique but there is no guarantee, and it is not possible to use as a device address on the internet.

When you use internet you use IP protocol (A global address system)
When your on a local network the devices usually use MAC addresses.

Comment: I got your point. thanks. but my question was different. what is the code  in socket programming in java to get MAC ADDRESS without using IP ADDRESS.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't. A socket is an IP/port configuration. MAC adresses are usually encapsuled into TCP/UDP packets. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket

Answer (score -1):

```
 try{       

InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("ip : " + ip);NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);
byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();
System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
String s=sb.toString();System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: As the OP said in the title: "without using IP address".